# I can't update my database through textbox

Tags: asp.net

I can't update my database through textbox. In the database `prt` is declared as a char datatype. It didn't show any error message.

My coding is...

```
SqlCommand cmdup= new SqlCommand("UPDATE [port1] SET [prt1]=@prt1 WHERE [no]= 1",cn);
cmdup.Parameters.Add("@prt1", TextBox1.Text); 
cmdup.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the exception you are getting?

Not related to your question but I must add that it's always a bad idea to store a user input directly into your DB. You should at least validate the input before using it.

Comment: this is not always true, it depends on the situation. In this case it might be good enough to use sql parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a lack of information I can't give you a well informed response, but one thing that comes to mind is parameter placeholder notation. The "@prt" notation is used by the System.Data.SQLClient namespace. System.Data.OleDb uses "?" as a placeholder.